# PostgreSQL 12 include variable in select statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an SQL query which look like this

```
SELECT t.test1 AS test01
FROM my_test_table t
WHERE t.test01 LIKE any('{data_nr0%,data_nr1%,data_a%}')
```

It works and everything is fine, but I don't know how to enhance it that
in the output it would include extra pieces of data that are in ANY().

I need an output to be

| test01 | parameter_ |
| --- | --- |
| data_nr0123 | data_nr0 |
| data_nr0122 | data_nr0 |
| data_nr0124 | data_nr0 |
| data_nr1123 | data_nr1 |
| data_nr1122 | data_nr1 |
| data_nr1124 | data_nr1 |
| data_a123 | data_a |

where **parameter_** column has values that are inside ANY() operator.

**UPDATE NO. 1**

Tried

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(t.test1, 1, 8), t.test1 AS test01
FROM my_test_table t
WHERE t.test01 LIKE any('{data_nr0%,data_nr1%}')
```

but this works only if values in **ANY operator** are of the same length.
How to make it work with variable length values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find a relevant match with CASE

```
SELECT case when t.test01 LIKE 'data_nr0%' then 'data_nr0'
            when t.test01 LIKE 'data_nr1%' then 'data_nr1' end param
, t.test1 AS test01
FROM my_test_table t
WHERE t.test01 LIKE any('{data_nr0%,data_nr1%}')
```

Alternatively you can have a parameters table / cte, then

```
-- sample data
with my_test_table(test01) as(
    select 'data_nr01' union all
    select 'data_nr13' 
),
params(val) as (
    select 'data_nr0' union all
    select 'data_nr1' 
)
SELECT t.test01, min(p.val)
FROM my_test_table t
JOIN params p on t.test01 like p.val||'%'
GROUP BY t.test01
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, what if there are many values inside ANY() (let's say
100 values), should I write them all in case... when... Or is there a better approach?